# Toit.io ESP32 Connot change wifi password through device

Tags: wifi, esp32, toit

I am trying to change password of device through code. It is giving this error. I have attached screenshot. Please help me.

[Screenshot from toit.io console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO2tW.png)

Comment: Please [do not post screenshots of error messages and/or code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) - post as text here.

Answer (score 0):

The toit.io version does not support changing the WiFi credentials from code.

That's only possible in the open-source version.